# Opencart 3 cart icon

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

ive styled my cart icon, updated the common.js to reflect the changes as well for adding/removing/editing cart, which all works fine.

For some reason though, if i add an item to the cart, the icon reverts back to old code, rather than using the new one...

See below :

cart.twig :

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}" class="cartBtn dropdown-toggle">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart cartIcon"></i>
    <div class="badge"><span id="cart-total">{{ text_items }}</span></div>
  </button>
```

What is displayed when adding product :

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="cartBtn dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false">
<span id="cart-total"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 3</span></button>
```

So for some reason, my "badge" class isnt being added to the code when adding an item to the cart. I've checked everywhere, updated everything i can think of, and its still not working. Removing an item from the cart, the icon stays the same, as it should, its just on adding an item...

Any ideas where to look?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you add an item a call to https://yourstore.com/index.php?route=common/cart/info fetches the whole html of cart update it in the page.

When you remove an item it doesn't updates the whole html.

So you need to see if your browser is retrieving the cached html on adding the same product while testing.

Try it in a new browser with cached removed.
If you are using any cache plugin that might be a reason.